# автоматическая отправка email в Android

Tags: java, android

Видел методы, где запускается активити и где кнопку отправить приходится нажимать пользователю 
Есть ли методы,  позволяющие автоматически отправлять сообщения на указанный email?
Мне нужно отправлять файл

Comment: Точно так же, как и при нажатии кнопки. Только инициирующий событием надо сделать не нажатие кнопки, а то, после чего вы хотите отправить имейл.

Comment: не уж-то всё так просто?
ответ снизу выглядит более реальным
кому верить ?

Comment: Что именно просто? Не говоря уже о том, что мой комментарий и ответ ниже совсем не противоречат друг другу.

Comment: как я понял, вы предлагаете отправлять его штатными средствами
а в примере ниже все настройки прописываются вручную

Comment: Настройки и какими средствами отправлять это совершенно разные вещи. Я говорю совсем о другом. Если имейл отправляется в результате нажатия кнопки, функция отправки имейла (совершенно неважно какие библиотеки используются и как она выглядит и где настраивается) вызывается в методе onClick() той самой кнопки. Вам же нужно вызывать эту же самую функцию отправки имейла не в onClick() кнопки, а в другом месте. Там, где вы хотите отправить имейл. Например (псевдокод): ``sensor_Temperature.isNegative() {sendEmail (address, subj, body, attachment);}``

Comment: в результате вывоза этого события `(Intent.ACTION_SEND)`
открывается активити, которое требует непосредственного взаимодействия с пользователем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По видимому вы имеете ввиду вызов `Intent.ACTION_SEND`, который подразумевает привлечение юзера чтобы отправить сообщение.

Если вы хотите обойтись совсем без юзера, то вам нужно смотреть в сторону JavaMail API, который в Android работает.

Подробная инструкция [лежит здесь](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-send-an-email-with-javamail-api-in-android-2fc405441079)

Если вкратце, то надо использовать класс `GMailSender`, который выглядит так:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
  private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
  private String user;
  private String password;
  private Session session;

  static {
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
  }

  public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
  }

  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
  }

  public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
    String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setDataHandler(handler);

    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
      message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    else
      message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

    Transport.send(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, буду тестить

Comment: все отлично работает, спасибо за ссылочку большое )