# Отправка электронной почты (email) автоматически (без взаимодействия с пользователем) на Mail.ru, Yandex.ru на Андроид

Tags: android, email, mail.ru

**Отправка электронной почты** (email) **автоматически** (без взаимодействия с пользователем) на **Mail.ru**, **Yandex.ru** на Андроид. (Отправка email автоматически) (без участия пользователя)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где взять рабочий (годный) пример отправки почты хотя бы на **Mail.ru**?

Вот хорошие примеры. Но они все для почты **Gmail.com** (мне же нужно хотя бы для **Mail.ru**)

Автоматическая отправка email в Android для **Gmail**:
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805183/автоматическая-отправка-email-в-android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805183/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-email-%D0%B2-android)

Отправка E-Mail с помощью **Gmail**:
https://habr.com/ru/post/112450/7

Send mail using SMTP means **Gmail**:
https://github.com/arpit999/SendMail

Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Электронная почта и работа с ней в Java-приложениях:
https://habr.com/ru/post/526162/

P.S. Как сделать отправку почты c помощью **Intent** типа:
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)...  я знаю.)) Эта отправка требует взаимодействия с пользователем.

Comment: По идее должно работать и по первой ссылке, если `gmail` на `mail` заменить. Ещё у них есть API для почты, но не уверен, что оно всем доступно, возможно надо корпоративный аккаунт в их системе иметь.

Comment: Должен работать из первого примера, только надо указать верные хосты и порты (у mail.ru там как то все нестандартно по моему).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберем `mail.ru`, настройки должны быть такие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Важным является пункт по-поводу [пароль для внешнего приложения](https://help.mail.ru/mail/settings/2fa/apps), который необходимо создавать отдельно.